# Loading Firebase childs dont works

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

So I made some childs in Firebase and wanted to load them as a list view in Flutter, so I made a Scaffold and this is whats inside the Body:

```
FutureBuilder(
    future: _Ref.get(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
        return CircularProgressIndicator.adaptive();
      }
      if(snapshot.hasError) {
        return Text(snapshot.error.toString());
      } else {
        List<Widget> _list = [];
        _Ref.once().then((DataSnapshot) async {
          final data = await DataSnapshot.snapshot.children.toList();
          data.forEach((element) async {
            final value = await element.value.toString();
            print(value);
            _list.add(ListTile(
              title: Text(value),
              trailing: Icon(
                Icons.delete_outlined,
              ),
            ));
          });

        });
        print(_list);
        return ListView(
          children: _list,
        );
      }
    },
  ),
```

my output looks like this:

[image: output]

this is what my Firebase database looks like:

[image: Firebase Database]

But the funny thing is that if I hotreload my app it works how it is supposed to

Answer (score 0):

My educated guess is that you expected 2 lines in the output, instead of the 3 lines you get.

When the Firebase SDKs see sequential, numeric keys in a snapshot, they assume that this snapshot is an array. If there's one or a few keys missing in that array, it fill them with `null` values. So in your database screenshot, the Firebase SDK sees an array with indexes 1 and 2, and index 0 missing.

If you want to prevent this array coercion, don't use sequential numeric keys in your data structure. You can most easily prevent this by calling `push()` to generate a unique key for you, or you can prefix the existing values with a short non-numeric string, e.g. `"key1"`, `"key2"`.

I recommend checking out this vintage blog post: [Best Practices: Arrays in Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html) on why using such array-like keys is typically an antipattern in Firebase.